# aligne h1 text to the bottom of the box

Tags: html, css

How to align the text within an h1 box to the bottom of it.

```
<h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title">All</h1>
```

[image]

Here's the current css:

```
    h1.woocommerce-products-header__title, h1.entry-title {
        font-family: 'Noe Display Bold', Times, serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 24px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    h1.entry-title {
        text-transform: none;
    }
```

I am inspecting using Chrome Version 81.0.4044.92 on Ubuntu.

Comment: add `jpq` and you will see it's already aligned to the bottom

Comment: what's `jpq` please?

Comment: letters -->`<h1>jqp</h1>`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are seeing the line height. So your fix might be: `line-height: 1`.
But when your H1 will wrap long texts this will result in unreadable text.

(I assume you checked the bottom padding)